# solution to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_{i}x+b_{i}} = 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Is there any general procedure to solve the equation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_{i}x+b_{i}}=0
$$
with respect to $x$ for given $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$, with $i=1,\dots,n$?

Comment: For $n\ge 5$, you end up with a degree-$n$ algebraic equation, for which no general solution exists. For $n\le 4$, you can always solve for $x$ and obtain the exact roots. So, no. There is no general method for solving this type of problem except there is some relation between $a_i,b_i$.

Comment: Comment: Consider the poles $p_j = - b_j/a_j$, ordered so that $p_j < p_{j+1}$. If $a_j a_{j+1} > 0$, ($a_j a_{j+1} < 0$), then the number of roots $x^*$ satisfying $p_j < x^* < p_{j+1}$ is a non-negative odd (even) integer. This gives you a lower bound on the number of roots, and a rough estimate of their positions.

Comment: If you have problems to get my paper, send me an e-mail (my address is in my profile) and I shall send you a copy of it. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ComptonScattering. If you look at the paper, you will see a methodology which gives good (not rough) estimates of the roots.

Comment: I added a bunch of material for your curiosity.

Comment: Since it is a single equation with single unknown $x$, tagging with systems of equations seems misplaced.  Asking for "any general procedure" leaves it to Readers to guess whether numerical or analytic solutions are required.  Please add context, such as where this problem arose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, for $n>4$, a numerical method will be required.

In fact, as you wrote it, your equation is just a variant of the so-called Underwood equation which write
$$F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i}{b_i -x}+c =0$$ which is widely used in chemical engineering.

In my former research group, we developed rapid and robust methods for obtaining the solutions. Have a look at [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0098135414003019).

Still closer to your specific problem, look at [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378381217303199?via%3Dihub) which addresses the problem of the solution of the so-called Rachford-Rice equation
$$G(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {z_i}{x-b_i } =0$$ which is also widely used in chemical engineering.

**Illustration**

I shall not use any of the above methods to show how you could treat the problem with a spreadsheet. Let
$$H(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {1}{a_ix+b_i } =0$$ and I shall admit that terms have been sorted such that
$$\frac{b_1}{a_1} >\frac{b_2}{a_2}> \cdots >\frac{b_n}{a_n}$$ and that we search for the solution between two vertical asymptotes, say
$$x_1=-\frac{b_1}{a_1} < x <-\frac{b_2}{a_2}=x_2$$ In a first step, remove this asymptotes and consider instead the function
$$\tilde H(x)=(a_1x+b_1)(a_2x+b_2) \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {1}{a_ix+b_i } $$
So, we have
$$\tilde H(x_1)=b_2-\frac{a_2}{a_1}b_1 \qquad  \qquad \tilde H(x_2)=b_1-\frac{a_1}{a_2}b_2\qquad \qquad \tilde H(x_1)\,\tilde H(x_2)<0$$
Draw the straight line joining the two points and compute the $x$ intercept. This defines a new point
$$x_3=-\frac{b_1+b_2}{a_1+a_2}$$
Computing $\tilde H(x_3)$ defines now either $x_1 <x<x_3$ or $x_3<x<x_2$ and you could continue just with bisection.

To make an example : $n=6$, $a_i=p_i$ and $b_i=\sqrt{i!}$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
i &x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_{\text{solution}} \\
 1 & -0.500000 & -0.471405 & -0.482843 & -0.479100 \\
 2 & -0.471405 & -0.489898 & -0.482963 & -0.493248 \\
 3 & -0.489898 & -0.699854 & -0.612372 & -0.672910 \\
 4 & -0.699854 & -0.995859 & -0.880746 & -0.961714 \\
 5 & -0.995859 & -2.064063 & -1.574469 & -1.978404
\end{array}
\right)$$ and this is the first iteration of the most simplistic numerical method.

Comment: does the algorithm work for any values of $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ or should they always be positive?

Comment: @AnTlr.  For your formula, they could be anything.

Comment: Excuse me, and for your formula, ie. $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{b_{i} -x}$?

Comment: @AnTlr. No problem ! $b_i$ could be positive or negative. For $a_i$, I must confess that I never tried negative value but I do not see what could be the problem.